# Variables gets lost after deleting/empting source input

Tags: javascript, cordova, variables, input, dom-events

I'm building a Phonegap application for Android - I'm taking some inputs values and put them to variables, e.g.

```
var a = $('input.myInput').val();
a
150
```

But then, when I remove/delete input like this:

```
$('input.myInput').remove();
```

my 'a' variable lost its value:

```
a
null
```

why js is updating variable value - can I somehow prevent from doing it?

BTW. I'm doing everything in on('click') event loop/block - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Are you under the same closure when checking `a` the second time?

Comment: Yes, it's under the same closure.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your a variable before your click function. In the click function, just set your a variable.